# Check for a dominance

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to apply Dominated convergence theorem to $f_n(x)=n\log\left(1+\frac{e^{-2x}}{n^2}\right)\sin{n},\ n\geq1$ in order to compute $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^\infty f_n(x) dx$.

Is it true that:

1. $\sin(x)\leq x$ when $x$ is positive
2. $\log(1+x)\leq x$

Then, if both are true I wold find the dominant function $g(x)$ in this way

$f_n(x)=n\log\left(1+\frac{e^{-2x}}{n^2}\right)\sin{n} \leq n\left(\frac{e^{-2x}}{n^2}\right)n=e^{-2x}:=g(x)$.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but you probably want to re-express things in terms of $\frac{\sin(n)}{n}$

Comment: Yes both are true but you have to upper bound $|f_n(x)|$ not $f_n(x)$. In that case $|\sin n| \leq 1$.

Comment: So, is my $g(x)$ wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both inequalities are true.

Set $f(x) = x - \sin x$ and observe that $f(0) =0 $ and $f^\prime (x) = 1 - \cos x \geq 0$, which implies that $f(x)$ is non-decreasing. Thus, $f(x) \geq 0$ and $x \geq \sin x$.

You may argue similarly for $g(x) = x - \log (1+x)$.

Comment: But if both are true, why my $g(x)$is wrong? because I tried with $n=20$ and $x=1$ and it seems that $f_n>g$

Comment: Are you sure you've calculated that correctly? $\log (1 + e^{-2}/400) \approx 0.00034 < 1 $.

Comment: you are correct, sorry. Do you finally confirm that my dominant function $g(x)$ is correct?

Comment: @Fabio Yes; your argument shows that on $[0,\infty]$ we have $|f_n| \leq g \in L^1$ for all $n$, which is the condition for LDCT.